# update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?

Tags: json

The best way I know of now is to run npm info express version then update package.json manually for each one. There must be a better way.

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "description": "my node project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.4",
    "npm": "1.1.65"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.0.3", // how do I get these bumped to latest?
    "mongodb": "~1.2.5",
    "underscore": "~1.4.2",
    "rjs": "~2.9.0",
    "jade": "~0.27.2",
    "async": "~0.1.22"
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the versions in the package.json to use * instead as the version number and then npm install, that should do the trick for you :)